# Add users is faded out on Azure Active Directory newly created app

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim2

I'm testing my SCIM integration with Azure AD. I created an app in Azure active directory, provisioning credentials are OK, but Add user option is not active (faded out).
When I create Databricks scim intergration, it's ok and it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due lack of permissions or appropiate role being assigned. Ensure you're assigned one ([Tenant or application scoped](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/hallelujah-azure-ad-delegated-application-management-roles-are/ba-p/245420#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20AD%20delegated%20application%20management%20roles%20are,people%20to%20create%20application%20registrations.%20By...%20More%20)) or be [added as owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/delegate-app-roles#assign-application-owners) of the application.

Comment: I had to relogin few times in few minutes and then it came back to work.